# Fastest way to change the values of an association

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, associations

I have an association of the following form :

```
assoc = Association[a -> {1, 2, 3}, b -> {5, 6, 7}]

<|a -> {1, 2, 3}, b -> {5, 6, 7}|>
```

(the size of actual lists in assoc is 30).

If I want to change the value of the list associated to a in the following manner: `assoc[a][[1]] = 2`, it does not work. I understand why mostly, I have looked it up (some mutability stuff e_e) !

by searching the forum, I didn't find any better than:

```
temp=assoc[a]
temp[[1]]=2
AssociateTo[assoc,a->temp]
```

I have two questions :

Between changing *in place* the value of a very big list (very) or changing the value of a very big association like demonstrated above, which is faster ?

Second, is there a better way to change the value of elements of the list associated to key a in assoc ?i.e. without the copying process.

Thank you.

Comment: You need to use single `Part` call and wrap the key(s) in `Key`: `assoc[[Key[a], 1]] = 2`

Answer (score 2):

```
asc = Association[a -> {1, 2, 3}, b -> {5, 6, 7}];
```

Using `ReplaceAt` (new in 13.1)

```
ReplaceAt[_ :> 2, {Key[a], 1}] @ asc
```

<|a -> {2, 2, 3}, b -> {5, 6, 7}|>

Using `MapAt`

```
MapAt[2 &, {Key[a], 1}] @ asc
```

<|a -> {2, 2, 3}, b -> {5, 6, 7}|>

If we want to change `asc` inline (see comment) we can use `ApplyTo`
(new in 12.2)

```
asc //= MapAt[2 &, {Key[a], 1}];

asc
```

<|a -> {2, 2, 3}, b -> {5, 6, 7}|>

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that

```
assoc[a][[1]] = 2
```

does not work, because it allows `assoc[a]` to evaluate first. But

```
assoc[[Key[a],1]] = 2
```

works just fine. If the association keys are strings then the `Key` wrapper is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
assoc = Association[a -> {1, 2, 3}, b -> {5, 6, 7}]
```

Using `SubsetMap`:

```
SubsetMap[{2} &, assoc, {{1, 1}}]

(*<|a -> {2, 2, 3}, b -> {5, 6, 7}|>*)
```